# How to get the nested child IDs from table using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two tables,Table1 and Table2.
Table1 is having SectionIDs that need to be excluded from tree. 
[image]

Table2 is having ParentID and its ChildIDs. There is a scenario A parentID has a child which is aparent of another child and so on. I need to get all the childIDs of parentID present in Table1 from Table2.

Example Table1 has SectionId 20000448 which is parent of 20000449 which is a parent of 20000543 (see the below image). I need to get all the childIds and subchildIds of 2000448.

i.e, result should be 2000448(which is present in Table1) have childIds 20000449,20000450,20000452,20000543,20000544,20000490,20000739,20000740,20000741.
(Here I am taking SubchildIDs from 20000449. If 20000450 has childIDs they also need to be considered. )

I have tried to use CTE but it is not giving the expected result.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the CTE?

Comment: Google for recursive hierarchical query.

Comment: Not sure if CTEs are sql-server only, so please tag your DBMS. Also, how many levels of parent-children will there be maximum? If there's no bound, you'll have to use a looping structure.

Comment: @lad2025.. I have added the CTE used, but it is giving only first level childIDs

Comment: One way to do this is to add a rootid to each item. You can then query all children in one go by searching for rootid = x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, seems a pretty straightforward recursion. It's hard to test without a text example but try with the following:

```
;WITH Hierarchy AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        RootID = T.ParentID,
        DescendantID = T.ParentID,
        Level = 0
    FROM
        Table2 AS T
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'records without parents' FROM Table2 AS N WHERE N.ChildID = T.ParentID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        RootID = H.RootID,
        DescendantID = T.ChildID,
        Level = H.Level + 1
    FROM
        Hierarchy AS H
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS T ON H.DescendantID = T.ParentID
)
SELECT
    H.RootID,
    H.DescendantID,
    H.Level
FROM
    Hierarchy AS H
ORDER BY
    H.RootID,
    H.Level
```

To exclude the records from your `Table1` you can use `NOT EXISTS` at the end or at the recursion, depending on your needs (stopping at the recursion will invalidate posterior children of records from `Table1`).

**EDIT:** To work with sample data and temporary table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Table2

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    ChildID INT,
    ParentID INT)

INSERT INTO #Table2 (
    ChildID,
    ParentID)
VALUES
    (20000449, 20000448),
    (20000450, 20000448),
    (20000452, 20000448),

    (20000543, 20000449),
    (20000544, 20000449),

    (20000490, 20000543),

    (20000739, 20000490),
    (20000740, 20000490),
    (20000741, 20000490)

;WITH Hierarchy AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        RootID = T.ParentID,
        DescendantID = T.ParentID,
        Level = 0
    FROM
       #Table2 AS T
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'records without parents' FROM #Table2 AS N WHERE N.ChildID = T.ParentID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        RootID = H.RootID,
        DescendantID = T.ChildID,
        Level = H.Level + 1
    FROM
        Hierarchy AS H
        INNER JOIN #Table2 AS T ON H.DescendantID = T.ParentID
)
SELECT
    H.RootID,
    H.DescendantID,
    H.Level
FROM
    Hierarchy AS H
ORDER BY
    H.RootID,
    H.Level
```

Result:

```
RootID  DescendantID    Level
20000448    20000448    0
20000448    20000449    1
20000448    20000450    1
20000448    20000452    1
20000448    20000543    2
20000448    20000544    2
20000448    20000490    3
20000448    20000739    4
20000448    20000740    4
20000448    20000741    4
```

Comment: This is giving the tree level. But how can we get sub levels from this

Comment: @Sarat can you elaborate more on your desired output?

Comment: I have added some more info. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: @Sarat this query should give you what you are requesting, I just tested it. Why you say it doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: How can I get the childIDs of 20000448 from this query. I have added the the list of ChildIDs to get as result, Can you please help

Comment: @Sarat make sure that 20000448 isn't a child of another one. If you want to calculate all childs for all records (even if it's on mid-tree) then remove the NOT EXISTS from the first part of the CTE.